# Checking that at least Value in HashMap matches?

Tags: java, for-loop, hashmap

I am trying to figure out how to iterate through my `HashMap` to see if at *least one* Value in it matches what I am looking for.

```
for(int i=0; i<allDogsInkennels.size(); i++){
    Map<String, DogStatus> allDogsStatus = allDogsInKennels.get(i).getAllStatuses();

}
```

How can I add an `If statement` / `loop` here to check that at least one of the statuses matches e.g. "APPROVED".

**Note:** String= the Dogs Id
      ,DogStatus= Enum showing dog's status

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if (allDogsStatus.containsValue(DogStatus.APPROVED)) {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: This seems to be the most elegant solution of them all, does it iterate through the key-value pairs one by one to check status?

Comment: In general yes, it will iterate, but it's up to the implementation of `Map`.

Comment: Yes it does.  If you want to avoid that, you'll have to use another data structure.  If you have proper encapsulation, you can add some code where they status is set and do some extra accounting.

Comment: @JimmyJames Yes, keeping like a `Map<DogStatus, Set<String>> dogsByStatus;` in parallel can help out for this sort of thing.

Comment: @Radiodef Right.  I've also implemented custom data structures (wrapping standard ones) too for this kind of issue but generally, it's overkill unless this comes up a lot.  I'm not familiar with any maps that provide any sort of optimization on value searches but they could exist

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate over the map and stop if you hit a match:

```
boolean found = false;
for (DogStatus value : allDogsStatus.values()) {
    if (value == DogStatus.APPROVED) {
        found = true;
        break;
    }
}
```

Even better is to refactor the above into a function that return the `boolean`.

Edit: I feel dumb for not remembering the `containsValue` method. That's probably the best approach, even though complexity is the same.